# need help in webservice

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am new to webservice first i used eclipse for consuming a third party free webservice "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL" tested the webservice successfuly the following java files are created in my src folder

- StockQuote.java
- StockQuoteLocator.java
- StockQuoteSoap12Stub.java
- StockQuoteSoap.java
- StockQuoteSoapStub.java
- StockQuoteSoapProxy.java

then i tried without eclipse this time using axis and command prompt, added all the D:\axis-1_4\lib jars to my class-path

executed the following command

```
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL
```

now i got only

- StockQuote.java
- StockQuoteLocator.java
- StockQuoteSoap12Stub.java
- StockQuoteSoap.java
- StockQuoteSoapStub.java

the file StockQuoteSoapProxy.java is missing i have tried my times but unable to get StockQuoteSoapProxy.java file

Answer (score 1):

With this command line you will be able to generate all:

wsdl2java -uri http://xxxxxxxx/?wsdl -p client.package -d xmlbeans -s